# Trying to append a list to a dataframe, and match based on IDs

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have a dataframe with 89 fields.  I'm using just a couple to do K_Means clustering.  I have the AccountIDs, and the clusters that each ID falls into.  Here is the list, named 'details'.

```
 ('38380AT31', 17),
 ('36295KCN1', 0),
 ('3132KFBD3', 14),
 ('3130A8X40', 14),
 ('912796SD2', 22),
 ('3617AVGD4', 0),
 ('03H0716A9', 0),
 ('912828LA6', 22),
 ('3133EJY29', 8),
 ('36176DHG1', 0),
 ...]
```

Now, I am trying to figure out how to add a new field to my existing dataframe and match the cluster IDs to the appropriate account IDs.  I tried this line of code, below.

```
df = df.append(details, ignore_index=True)
```

This runs, but it doesn't seem to append the cluster IDs to the dataframe (and the ignore_index=True looks suspicious).  Then, I tried this line of code.

```
df['details'] = df.append([details],index=df['AccountID'].index)
```

This throws an error, stating: `TypeError: append() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'`

I hope I explained everything well enough.  What am I missing here?

Comment: `df['details'] = np.array(details)` is what I normally do. This would work if `details` has the same length as that of your `df`.

Comment: When I do this: len(details)
df.shape

I see both are 10000 records.  That's exactly what I would expect.  When I run your code, I get this error: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1.

Comment: Also, shouldn't there be a way to match on the AccountID?  Otherwise, what kind of guarantee do you have that the ClusterID in the list is associated with the correct AccountID in the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

I made an attempt at this and got this done:

**Code:**

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'AccountID':['38380AT31','36295KCN1','3132KFBD3']})
ls=[('38380AT31', 17),
 ('36295KCN1', 0),
 ('3132KFBD3', 14)]

ls.sort()
df.sort_values(by=['AccountID'],inplace=True)    #sorting both df and list to get the same AccountID in the right index

a=[]
for i in range(0,len(ls)):
    a.append(ls[i][1])         

df['col']=a
```

**Output:**

```
df

    AccountID   col
2   3132KFBD3   14
1   36295KCN1   0
0   38380AT31   17
```

This assumes that the list has no duplicates and the right count as the dataframe. It is a crude way, but it will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the look.  I did a little more research and came up with this.

```
details_df = pd.DataFrame(details)
details_df.columns = ['AccountNo','ClusterID']
finalDF = pd.merge(dataset, details_df, left_index=False, right_index=False, how='inner')
```